# Node js and npm installation of nodemon globally problems

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

**I'm learning Web Development . For this I've install nodejs:. And I've run following command on CMD:**

```
npm install nodemon --global
```

After some time following error occured

```
PS C:\Users\SANKET PRAKHER\Desktop\complete web development bootcamp\web dev tutorials\tut70> npm install nodemon --global
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\SANKET PRAKHER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\SANKET PRAKHER\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\SANKET PRAKHER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js' -> 'C:\Users\SANKET PRAKHER\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\SANKET PRAKHER\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SANKET PRAKHER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-20T14_40_01_614Z-debug.log
```

Can you please explain what is that error and how I could solve this. I am using Window 10

Comment: Did you read the message? *"file already exists"* - the `nodemon.js` file already exists, so it looks like you already have nodemon globally installed.

Comment: ok thanks I am just trying to delete that file hope it works